Finding an equation for a series of non-linear points
I'm currently working on implementing the gain function (a function that applies contrast to an image) of ImageData (Open Office XML see https://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/OfficeOpenXML/2006/?page=imagedata.html). The only thing mentioned in the documentation is that values can be from 0 to Infinity.
While trying to reverse engineering this function within Microsoft Excel, these are the values I found:
$f(0) = 0$
$f(25) = 0.5$
$f(50) = 1$
$f(75) = 2$
$f(80) = 2.5$
$f(95) = 10$
$f(98) = 25$
$f(99) = 50$
$f(100) = \infty$
How would I go about finding an equation that represents this pattern?

Please, show us what you have tried!

I recommend plotting the points first and seeing if they appear to (roughly) follow the shape of any functions you know. Once you have that, add parameters to the guess and apply the least-squares method if you're able, or at least play around with the parameters until you get within your desired accuracy. For the record, you say "exponential" in the title, but that doesn't seem like a good guess to me due to the vertical asymptote. You could start with the guess $f(x) = A + \frac{B}{1 - (x/100)^C}$

Welcome to MSE. When you say $f(100)=\infty$, is this a limit? (is $f(100)$ defined, or is it an asymptote?

@RedFive I'll give a little more context to the issue. I've been working on this problem trying to apply contrast to an image within an Open Office XML document.
The actual function on how to apply the contrast is not provided by the open office documentation, the only thing they mention is that it accepts values between 0 and Infinity. I tried to reverse engineer the way Microsoft Office does it and got these values. For 0% maps to 0, 25% -> 0.5, 50% -> 1, 75% -> 2, 80% -> 2.5 ......100% -> 1e99.
I have been trying to figure out the formula but no luck :(

Your function has a vertical asymptote at $x = 100$. The simplest kind of function with this behavior is just $f(x) = 1/(100 - x)$. Already we can see that $f(x)$ is positive, gives small values for small $x$, and tends towards infinity as $x \to 100$. Of course, it would be miraculous that this function fit the data by itself, so we need to add parameters that we can modify. As in the comments, I suggest:
$$f(x) = A + \frac{B}{1 - \left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^C}$$
as a starting point. If this function perfectly fit the data, then in principle we would just need to plug in $3$ separate known values to create $3$ equations for $A, B,$ and $C$ that we could solve. If not, we can optimally choose values (i.e. find the parameters that best fit the data) using something like the least-squares method. What you choose to do ultimately depends on how accurate you need your model to be.
As a start, we know that $f(0) = 0$, which directly tell us that $A + B = 0$. This lets us reduce the number of parameters in our model. That is, we are now working with
$$f(x) = B\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^C} - 1\right)$$
Next, let's use $f(50)=1$.
\begin{align*}
1 &= B\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac12\right)^C} - 1\right) \\
&= B\left(\frac{2^C}{2^C - 1} - 1\right) \\
2^C - 1 &= B\left(2^C - (2^C - 1)  \right) \\
B &= 2^C - 1
\end{align*}
so that our model becomes
$$f(x) = (2^C - 1)\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^C} - 1\right)$$
Using the point $f(75) = 2$,
\begin{align*}
2 &= (2^C - 1)\left(\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac34\right)^C} - 1\right) \\
2 &= \frac{3^C(2^C - 1)}{4^C - 3^C}
\end{align*}
I don't suspect to have hope of solving this equation algebraically, but it's not difficult to see that the right-hand side is monotonically increasing, so there will be at most $1$ solution. By plotting, it's easily seen that it occurs at $C = -1$, which can be verified algebraically. Hence, with respect to our original model, $A = \frac12, \ B = -\frac12, \ C=-1$, and
$$f(x) = \frac12\left(1 - \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{100}{x}\right)}\right) = \frac{50}{100 -x}$$
Notice that we no longer have $f(0)= 0$, and we also fail to solve $f(25) = 0.5$. However, this choice in $f$ does perfectly interpolate every other you gave, and also has the vertical asymptote at $x = 100$.
It is worth noting that the first $3$ points you gave are collinear. In particular, $f(x) = \frac{x}{50}$ solves $f(0) = 0$, $f(25) = \frac12$, and $f(50) = 1$. My prediction, then, is that the contrast function behaves linearly up to $x = 50$, and then switches to the nonlinear model. That is, I suggest you try
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x}{50}, &0 \le x < 50\\ 
\frac{50}{100 - x}, &50 \le x < 100
\end{cases}$$
Here is a plot of the function, with the interpolation points in red:


Thanks for going through all of this to work it out that it was actually three solutions. One for > 99, another for < 100 and another for < 51. I was going for a one size fits all that would never work. Thanks again.
